# Disable iOS 8 QuickType in HTML input field

Tags: html, ios, ios8

Is it somehow possible to force iOS 8 to not display the QuickType predictions? With a data attribute, for instance? I already tried `autocomplete="off"`, but without success.

In some cases, it simply doesn't make much sense to display those kind of suggestions, like for address input fields. The predictions then just waste screen space that could be used better otherwise.

Answer (score 13):

i put `autocapitalize="off"` `autocomplete="off"` `autocorrect="off"`

and it works.

Comment: I only had to set `autocomplete="off"` `autocorrect="off"`. Thanks for this answer!

Answer (score 0):

No. This is on the iOS side: you can't control it via element properties.

Users can disable it themselves by

1. Swiping down on the menu itself,
2. Using the international keyboards button (globe icon), or
3. Disabling it in Settings.

However, there is currently no way to disable it via HTML without changing the `input` to a type other than `text`. The [`autocomplete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion) attribute merely tells the keyboard whether to store previous inputs and recommend those to the user as they're typing.

Comment: It is possible, set `autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off"`

Comment: That was on an 8.0 device. 8.1 I've checked also works.